# How to build a list of constraints for NMinimize

Tags: list-manipulation, mathematical-optimization

Let's say I have a`set = {-1, 0, 2}`. I would like to create a variable `Var` that takes values from that set, i.e. `var = -1` or `var = 0` or `var = 2`.
What I'm trying to do is using the variable in `NMinimize` as a constraint. A simple example could be as follow:

```
NMinimize[{a + 1, var == -1 || var == 0 || var == 2, a > 0}, a]
```

The result is, obviously:

> ```
> {1., {a -> 0.}}
> ```

But if the set is much larger I can't write down constraints for each element. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

#### Edit

Both answers work (see comments). However, if I change the code a bit,

```
set = {b^2, b^2 + 1, b^2 - 1};
NMinimize[{a + 1, Or @@ (a == # & /@ set)}, {a, b}]
```

gives

> ```
> {-7.45058*10^-9, {a -> -1., b -> -7.43726*10^-9}}`
> ```

while

```
NMinimize[{a + 1, Times @@ ((a - #)& @ set) == 0}, {a, b}]
```

gives

> ```
> {-3.53148*10^-9, {a -> -1., b -> -7.29659*10^-9}}
> ```

Both results are satisfactorily correct. However I notice that the second result is a little bit more accurate.

Comment: Try something like `NMinimize[{a + 1, {Or @@ (a == # & /@ {-1, 0, 2}) && a > 0}}, a]`?

Comment: Or `NMinimize[{a + 1, Times @@ ((a - #) &@{-1, 0, 2}) == 0}, a]`

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of the following, taken from the comments, will work.

kguler's answer.

```
NMinimize[{a + 1, {Or @@ (a == #& /@ {-1, 0, 2}) && a > 0}}, a]
```

belisarius' answer.

```
NMinimize[{a + 1, Times @@ ((a - #)& @ {-1, 0, 2}) == 0}, a]
```

Another possibility:

```
NMinimize[{a + 1, Or @@ Thread[a == {-1, 0, 2}] && a > 0}, a]
```